# Storing the text from an uncertain number of textfields in a list

Tags: java, jframe, jtextfield

I have a class "Book" and each book I don't know how many authors has. User will give me the number of authors and I store this number to the variable authors. This is the code which make the textfields.

```
FlowLayout layout2=new FlowLayout();    
for(int i=0;i<authors;i++)
{  
 JPanel row=new JPanel();
 JTextField author_name=new JTextField(20); 
 JLabel author_label=new JLabel("Author"+(i+1)+":");
 row.setLayout(layout2);
 row.add(author_label);
 row.add(author_name);      
 container.add(row);
 }
```

When the user press the button "store", I want to store every author name to a list. This is the code:

```
for(int i=0;i<authors;i++)
list_authors.add(author_name.getText());
```

The problem is that I get only the last author's name. Please help me. Thank you in advance

Comment: you're not using 'i', and you'll need to access 'cont'.

Comment: I can't understand you about the i

Comment: From for(int i=0;i<authors;i++)
list_authors.add(author_name.getText()); : author_name is just a field, you're not getting to the list of authors

Comment: You will have to keep references to every textbox, and call `getText()` on each of those.

Comment: Can you please give me a code to help me how to do it, because I can't understand you